# Does the Monodevelop Dnx Addin running on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 let us debug C# managed code with symbols or not

Tags: c#, linux, debugging, monodevelop, dnx

I found out today that when i install the Monodevelop AddInMaker and
 Monodevelop Monodevelop DNX Addin on top of Monodevelop 6.0 for Ubuntu
 Linux, that the Monodevelop Run Debugger submenu has a Monosoft DNX
 Debugger and a Microsoft .NET DNX Debugger. When I clicked on these
 two Debuggers from an new console C# project, I observed the error
 message, "Debugger activation not permitted"

I am interested in knowing whether the Monodevelop Dnx Addin will lets us debug C# managed code with symbols or not. Also, I would like to find out how to create a DNX C# Project using Monodevelop 6.0 and the Monodevelop AddInMaker and Monodevelop Monodevelop DNX Addin running on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.

What does it mean to migrate existing projects to the Addin Maker using the following steps?

- Add {86F6BF2A-E449-4B3E-813B-9ACC37E5545F} to the project's flavor
  GUIDs i.e. for C#:
  {86F6BF2A-E449-4B3E-813B-9ACC37E5545F};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4‌​B-00C04F79EFBC}
- Add a reference to the NuGet package monodevelop.addins
- Remove all references you have to the assemblies included with MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio. Remove all addin dependency declarations
  from your manifests and assembly attributes.
- Add Addin References for all of the dependencies you removed in the
  previous step.

Does DNX use the Roslyn csc.exe compiler?

Comment: @Matt Ward, Could I ask you to look at this Stack Overflow question when you have time? Thank you.

Comment: @shellter, I appreciate your nice edit.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck.

Comment: Here is Matt Ward's answer to our question immediately above. There is limited debugger support. If mono 4.3 is installed you can hit breakpoints. Debugging when running with the .net core CLR is not supported though only when running with mono. – Matt Ward 23 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

There is limited support for debugging DNX with the DNX addin for MonoDevelop. On Windows it is not supported at all. On Mac and Linux if you have Mono 4.3 installed and is being used to run MonoDevelop then you can hit breakpoints if you are using the Mono DNX runtime.

On Mac and Linux there are two possible DNX runtimes: Mono and .NET Core. These map to the frameworks: dnx451 and dnxcore50 in the project.json file. These runtimes are installed using the dnvm tool. Debugging when running with .NET Core is not supported. Debugging when using the DNX Mono runtime will hit breakpoints if you are running MonoDevelop with Mono 4.3. However the debugging experience is not that good currently.

The Addin Maker is only used to build and debug the DNX addin itself. You can generate an .mpack and install that into MonoDevelop so you do not have to debug the DNX addin from source. At some point I will release the DNX addin so you do not have to build it from source.

There are three project templates provided with the DNX addin in the Other - ASP.NET - ASP.NET 5 section in the New Project dialog.

> What does it mean to migrate existing projects to the Addin Maker
>   using the following steps?

There is no need to migrate anything. The addin maker is only used to build the DNX addin. It is not required for creating new DNX projects using the DNX addin if the DNX addin is installed into MonoDevelop.

> Does DNX use the Roslyn csc.exe compiler?

The addin uses the DNX host provided by Microsoft. This, as far as I am aware, uses parts from Roslyn but does not directly call the Roslyn csc.exe compiler. If you look in the ~/.dnx/runtimes directories you can see it includes some Roslyn .dlls such as Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll.

Comment: What combination of versions of mono and xamarin studio should work together? The ones I tried so far all lock up when loading the project

Comment: I tend to stick with the latest stable Mono and Xamarin Studio which is Mono 4.2.1 and Xamarin Studio 5.10.

Comment: Are you able to hit breakpoints? In your answer, you state you need Mono 4.3 for this to work? (I tried 4.3 but when loading the solution it gets stuck at loading the the project)

Comment: I have only tried Mono 4.3 on the Mac not on Linux. On the Mac I can hit breakpoints.

Comment: I'm on Mac and 4.3 didn't work. If you're back on Mac, can you tell me which versions and how you got them? Do you build both from source?

Comment: I downloaded [Mono 4.3](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/nightly/macos-10-universal/). I have 4.3.2.155 installed. If Xamarin Studio is hanging I would run `kill -QUIT pid` with the process id for Xamarin Studio. That should dump the thread callstacks in the IDE log (Help - Open Log Directory). I am assuming by "gets stuck" that the UI is hung.